# How can I detect the onChange event for the start and end date of the RangePicker?

Tags: reactjs, antd

I have a standard antd RangePicker on my app:

```
<RangePicker
  format="DD-MM-YYYY"
  onOpenChange={onOpenChange}
  disabled={loading}
  defaultValue={dateDefaultValue}
  onCalendarChange={onCalendarChange}
/>
```

According to [their documentation](https://ant.design/components/date-picker/#RangePicker), since version 4.4.0 there's an info argument, and I'm using the 4.10.3 version.

```
  const onCalendarChange = (dates, dateStrings, info) => {
    console.log(dates);
    console.log(dateStrings);
    console.log(info);
    if (dates?.length) {
      setStartDate(dates[0]);
      setEndDate(dates[1]);
    }
  };
```

Problem is: info is always undefined (It seems that the documentation is wrong about the version). Everytime the onChange or onCalendarChange event is triggered on the RangePicker, I get both dates, and I want to detect the events separately, so that I can specifically know when the start date changed or the end date changed. How can I achieve that if there's no onStartDateChange?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, seems like you're already saving the date in your state. What you can do is compare the dates coming to the onCalendarChange function with the dates saved in your state. That way you know which one changed.

---

PS: I think it works like that, because seems like you can change both start and end date in the same change?

Comment: I'll give you the right answer because essentially, you're right. Couldn't achieve what I wanted though, but it was because of a state management problem (When the user selects the startDate, I wanted the endDate to update to the startDate so that it can choose from there, and that behavior gets messed up by the defaultDate, which is also necessary as part of the business logic. So, I found myself in a crossroads and I think I'll leave it as it is, in order to avoid buggy calendar behavior / async state update nightmares.